# Where to find mounted folders inside a Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

Still pretty wet behind the ears with Docker (and only so-so with Linux); I've fired up a container with a few mounted folders.

I know that I can find the volumes at `/var/lib/docker/volumes` and `/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes`, but what I'm trying to find are the paths *inside the container*.

For example, I do a:
`-v my_mounted_volume:/config`

`my_mounted_volume` would be in the paths listed above, but if I wanted to go to `/config` instead, how do I get there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it inside the container, i.e.:

```
docker exec -it <container> sh
cd /config
```

Comment: Aha! That did it. I used `bash` instead of `sh` though. I'll mark as best answer in a few minutes when it lets me. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do `docker inspect <ContainerID>`.

It will list the source destination details.

Comment: Thanks. Yes but that only shows "/config". I was looking for a way to actually navigate there.